# Unable to retrieve the bean value in Hybris

Tags: java, spring, sap-commerce-cloud

I have defined the following bean in ***-spring.xml** file.

```
<bean id="userTimeZone"  class= "com.abc.UserTimeZoneHelper">
```

and I have set one of its variable like this:

```
@Resource
UserTimeZoneHelper userTimeHelper;

userTimeZoneHelper.setTimeZone("GMT+5");
```

But when I tried to access its value, am getting a null value.

```
UserTimeZoneHelper userTimeZone = (UserTimeZoneHelper) Registry.getApplicationContext().getBean("userTimeZone");
System.out.println(userTimeZone.getTimeZone());
```

Since the bean scope is Singleton, i should be able to access it from other class right?

Comment: you have defined var `userTimeHelper` but you are trying to access `userTimeZoneHelper`, It may be a typo.

Comment: please share the implementation of UserTimeZoneHelper class

Comment: Please, do not use stateful singleton beans unless you are very sure what you are doing. Otherwise you will have a lot of fun with race conditions between the various request processing threads.

Answer (score 0):

Try defining

```
<alias name="defaultUserTimeZone" alias="userTimeZone"/>
<bean id="defaultUserTimeZone" class="com.abc.UserTimeZoneHelper"/>
```

Access it like

```
@Resource(name="userTimeZone")
UserTimeZoneHelper userTimeHelper;

userTimeHelper.setTimeZone("GMT+5");
```